# как посчитать сумму чисел в промежутке рекурсия js

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция , как ее модифицировать под 2 значения , чтобы можно была считать от числа num1 к числу num2

```
function sumTo(n) {
if (n == 1) return 1;
return n + sumTo(n - 1);
}

alert( sumTo(100) );
```

Comment: обычный цикл for. Какие у вас с ним трудности?

Comment: так в том то и дело что циклом и не надо, нужно с использованием такой функции без цикла

Comment: Так-то, Гаусса на Вас нет)

Answer (score 2):

Почти так же:

```js
function sumFromTo(from, to) {
 if (from > to) return sumFromTo(to, from);
 if (to===from) return from;
 return from + sumFromTo(from+1, to);
}

console.log(sumFromTo(1, 100)); // 5050
console.log(sumFromTo(100, 1)); // 5050
```

Можно немножко уменьшить глубину стека:

```js
function sumFromTo(from, to) {
 if (to === from) return from;
 if (to === from + 1) return from + to;
 return from + to + sumFromTo(from + 1, to - 1);
}

console.log(sumFromTo(1, 100)); // 5050
console.log(sumFromTo(1, 99));  // 4950
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumTo(a,n){
if(n==a) return a;
return n + sumTo(a,n-1);
}

alert(sumTo(4,9));
```

Answer (score 1):

А рекурсия обязательна? А то можно ведь просто:

```js
function sumFromTo(n1, n2) {
  return (n1 + n2) * (n2 - n1 + 1) / 2;
}

console.log(sumFromTo(1, 99));
console.log(sumFromTo(2, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна рекурсия, можно использовать тернарный оператор:

```js
function sumTo(max, min) {
  return (max != 1) ? max + sumTo(max - 1) : 1;
}
console.log(sumTo(100, 1));
```